# Summing up floats elements of array in python is adding garbage value to the end of the answer?

Tags: python, arrays

My code is:

```
import array as arr

print("\t\t\tEnter Marks of the following subjects out of 100 :\n")

marks = arr.array('f') 


for x in range(5):
    marks.append(float(input("Enter marks of {0} subject : ".format(x+1))))

else:
    print("Calculating...")

sum = float(0.0)
for x in marks:
    sum += x

print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) = ",sum)
```

[Code and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O4Ko.jpg)

Comment: Also: you are using single precision floating points (type code `'f'`). Standard python `float`'s are double precision, and you should use that for basically everything (use type code `'d'` in `arr.array`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because floats are not exact values. So when you add them you often ends up with ,00001 or ,..999. One way to solve this is to round your final result. For example do :

```
print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) = ", round(sum,2))
```

You can check this [detailed article in Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-rounding/) on the matter, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are required to used the `array` library, but I don't see a use for it here. Do you want to use it to be more efficient? If that's the case then also see *2* In python you can set a variable's values as an empty `list`, so you can use it as one, further in your code. For example:

---

```py
l = []
for i in range(3):
    l.append(i)

print(l)  # prints [0, 1, 2]
```

So in your case you can do this:

***1)***

```py
print("\t\t\tEnter Marks of the following subjects out of 100 :\n")

marks = []
for x in range(5):
    marks.append(float(input("Enter marks of {0} subject : ".format(x+1))))

print("Calculating...")

sum = 0
for mark in marks:
    sum += x  # if x is a float in any of the loops then the sum will be a float.

print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) = ", sum)
```

Or if you are required to use the `array` package:

***2)***

```py
import array

marks = array.array("f")
for i in range(5):
    marks.append(float(input("Enter marks of {0} subject : ".format(i+1))))

sum = 0
for mark in marks:
    sum += mark

print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) =", float(sum))  # prints the float value of the sum
```

---

This doesn't seem like it needs to be that efficient and you probably wont be getting the program any faster by using the `array` library. Use the `timeit` module to see which program runs faster.

```py
import timeit

timeit.timeit(stmt="""import array

in_marks = [80, 80.2, 80, 80, 80]
marks = array.array("f")
for i in range(5):
    marks.append(float(in_marks[i]))

sum = 0
for mark in marks:
    sum += mark

# print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) =", float(sum))  # prints the float value of the sum""", number=1000000)

# This took 1.7964587999999821 seconds to run 1.000.000 times
# And 0.19057900000007066 to run 100.000 times
```

And this is without the library:

```py
import timeit

timeit.timeit(stmt="""
in_marks = [80, 80.2, 80, 80, 80]
marks = []
for i in range(5):
    marks.append(float(in_marks[i]))

sum = 0
for mark in marks:
    sum += mark

# print("Total Marks (Out Of 500) =", float(sum))  # prints the float value of the sum""", number=100000)

# This took 1.271052900000086 seconds to run 1.000.000 times
# And 0.12818579999998292 seconds to run 100.000 times
```

Python seems to be faster without it, because the program doesn't do any heavy calculations, so by importing the library you lose some time and don't gain any in the long run.

---

To remove the ending numbers in you code you can `round()` the float to 2 decimal points like @Laurent Bristiel suggested.